# dynamoDB / aws-amplify - Query with 'limit' + 'filter' - returns half empty or completely empty pages and not full with items with 'limit' amount

Tags: filter, amazon-dynamodb, limit, aws-amplify

***Code example:***

```
import { API, graphqlOperation } from "aws-amplify"

const fetchInitialAds = () => {
  const { filterAttributes } = useContext(FilterContext)

  const {
    query: { slug },
  } = useRouter()

  const fetchAds = async ({ pageParam = null }) => {

  const {
    deal_type,
    priceFrom,
    priceTo,
  } = filterAttributes

  const currTimeInSeconds = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000)

  const options = {
    subcategoryID: `SUBCATEGORY#${slug}`,
    sortDirection: "DESC",
    limit: 24,
    nextToken: pageParam,

    filter: {
      and: [
        {
          or: [
            {
              list_price: {
                between: [
                  Number(priceFrom) || 0,
                  Number(priceTo) || 100000000,
                ],
              },
            },
            {
              new_price: {
                between: [
                  Number(priceFrom) || 0,
                  Number(priceTo) || 100000000,
                ],
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  }

  const adsResult = await API.graphql(
    graphqlOperation(adsBySubcategoryByExpdate, options)
  )

  const data = await adsResult.data.adsBySubcategoryByExpdate

  return data
}

  return useInfiniteQuery(["ads", slug], fetchAds, {
    getNextPageParam: (currentPage, allPages) => currentPage.nextToken,
  })
}
```

**Problem** with 'Query' with 'limit' + 'filter' on a big database for example with 5000 items in it. If you limit down to show 24 items at a time (for pagination), the 'filter' expresion will filter only the first 24 items in your table and return matched items. If you get filter-match for 5 out of 24 first items it will return only these 5 items... <-- this means your first page you want to display for client will be not full with 24 items but only 5 items... and then u need to filter again next 24 items with 'nextToken'. This time maybe you get 10 matched items. So now you are displaying only 16 items for the client (still not full page of 24 items...). And lets say the third run on next 24 items u get 0 matched items <-- you will not get any new items to display your client. And it will feel wierd that - You clicked on Button to fetch next 24 items but got 0 items and you have to continue clicking that button till it hits some new matched items and till you have went throught the whole Table....

**So my question is:** Is there a solution where if you put a limit of 24 items, so that dynamo db collects full list of 24 matched items and only then return a full page? I dont want to get halffull pages and spam my 'Fetch more' button and see if i havnt missed any other filter-matched items......

Answer (score 4):

The fact that a `Query` operation first reads a page of data (1MB of data, or `Limit` rows if you specified that parameter), and only then does filtering on it, is deliberate and [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html):

> A single `Query` operation will read up to the maximum number of items set (if using the `Limit` parameter) or a maximum of 1 MB of data and then apply any filtering to the results using `FilterExpression`.  ... A `Query` operation can return an empty result set and a `LastEvaluatedKey` if all the items read for the page of results are filtered out.

The reason for this design is that it limits the *latency* and the *cost* of each request: Imagine a situation that in a 1 TB database you run a query with a filter that only matches 5 items. If the query were to continue until it can return 5 items, it would potentially read 1 TB of data before returning anything - which will cause huge latency (the client would most likely assume the connection broke and disconnect it before getting a response...), as well as huge cost. By returning an empty page each time the database reads 1 MB of data, the client remains aware that the query is progressing and doesn't time out - and also remains aware of the cost of this query and given an opportunity to stop it.

One could imagine a better API, which includes **both** a limit on the number of items *to read*, and a limit on the items *to return*, with a page being ended as soon as either one of these limits is reached. Unfortunately, DynamoDB doesn't have such an API. As you noticed you are forced to use a `Limit` and retry if not enough results were returned.

If you believe that the matching results are uniformly distributed across items, you can attempt to "guess" how big Limit should be to produce roughly the right number of results - and you can improve this guess as you go along. Guessing a too-low Limit just means you'll need to issue a second query, and guessing a too-high Limit just means you will have read a bit too much (and paid a bit too much), but in either case it's (usually) not a disaster. In any case you don't need the *user* to click to get more results - you can do it internally in code.

Comment: Yes. Everything you say is right. BUT - I have over 10K products and the user can filter to a specific product - but to find that specific product the whole ProductTable need to be iterated to make sure no filter-matched products were missed. In short sentence - each time client filters products the whole table needs to be checked. Right now i implemented 'Amazon OpenSearch Service' but its to expensive... There should be a better solution for this. I have a question: Maybe its cheaper to have a REST API for this kind of filtering? Or it doesnt metter - the cost will be the same at the end?

Comment: You should reconsider your data model - either organize the data differently, or use a GSI. Your goal would be to organize the data in a way that at read time, the right data can be retrieved without too much filtering. Iterating over 10,000 items just to find one that matches isn't just slow, it is also pretty expensive.

Comment: Thanks for info. I think i need a combo: Redesign the UX flow to norrow down the posible products + Database reorganisation... Sadly im just a Frontender :D Will be fun.

Comment: @NadavHar'El about this comment "...without too much filtering...". Frankly I don't understand how you can accomplish that...for example a user 'Caio' wants to search for another user 'Sempronio' and  you have 100k+ users in DB. It's just impossible to do different things...