# DynamoDB filtering before pagination

Tags: java, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am writing a request to DynamoDB in which I need to guarantee the number of items in the page. I am using java, awssdk. This is what my request looks like:

```
val keyEqual =
                sortBeginsWith(
                        key ->
                                key.partitionValue(source.getParrentEntityId())
                                        .sortValue(SOME_PREFIX.getValue() + "#"));
        val requestBuilder =
                QueryEnhancedRequest.builder()
                        .queryConditional(keyEqual)
                        .limit(source.getLimit())
                        .exclusiveStartKey(startKey);
        if (nonNull(source.getStatus())) {
            requestBuilder.filterExpression(
                    Expression.builder()
                            .expression("#status = :status")
                            .putExpressionName("#status", "st")
                            .putExpressionValue(
                                    ":status",
                                    AttributeValue.builder()
                                            .s(source.getStatus().toString())
                                            .build())
                            .build());
        }
        val pages = dynamoDbTable.query(requestBuilder.build());
```

I know that filtering is applied after pagination and tried to use scan instead of query, but I did not find information on how to add my sk and pk condition to the scan query. Can someone tell me how to solve my problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamoDB / aws-amplify - Query with 'limit' + 'filter' - returns half empty or completely empty pages and not full with items with 'limit' amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71816380/dynamodb-aws-amplify-query-with-limit-filter-returns-half-empty-or-c)

Comment: note DDB works the same way regardless of client

Answer (score 0):

In DynamoDB you cannot guarantee the number of items to be returned while filtering on non-key attributes. If your aim is to guarantee a set number of items you have two choices:

1. Make sure your items match your KeyConditionExpression so that you can read them without filtering which will return exactly what you ask.
2. Return more than you require, then limit the results on the client side to match your needs.

As for Scan, that will not fit your use case either, as all the APIs work the same way with filtering, filter is applied after the limit.